# How to start and break the loop by pressing a key on Python 3.x

Tags: python, keyboard

I have this code which breaks the loop when pressed the "P" key but the loop is not working unless I press a key that is not "P"

```
def main():
    openGame()
    while True:
        purchase()
        imageGrab()
        if a.sum() >1200:
            fleaButton()
            time.sleep (0.01)
        grab()
        if b.sum() <=9:
            pressOk()
            time.sleep (0.01)
        if keyboard.read_key() == "p":
            print("Stopping the bot.")
        break


print("Press 'F1' key to stop the bot.")
input("Press enter to start the bot.")

main()
```

I am a newbie on programming and dont know what to do with this :(

Also, I've been looking for a code that allows me pause the loop when I press a key and continue the loop when I press a key. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code and call `main()` as shown below:

```
from pynput import keyboard
import time
break_program = True
def on_press(key):
    global break_program
    print (key)
    if key == keyboard.Key.f1 and break_program:
        print ('end pressed')
        break_program = False

    if key == keyboard.Key.enter:
        print ('enter pressed')
        break_program = True


print("Press 'F1' key to stop the bot.")
print("Press enter to start the bot.")

listener =  keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
listener.start()
while True:
    if break_program:
        main()
        time.sleep(1)
```

You can install this package using `pip` as `pip install pynput`

Modify the code as per your needs. Right now it will not start on `Enter`. You can explore [`pynput`](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) package and customize your code.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. When I try to run it says 
AttributeError: module 'keyboard' has no attribute 'Listener'
Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: First install pynput package using `pip install pynput` then import keyboard using `from pynput import keyboard`

Comment: Thanks, it worked now. But when I run, neither F1 nor ENTER are not working :(

Comment: You are running the code in terminal or some ide? Also put some sleep time of 5 secs, and then check by pressing `F1` whether its getting stopped or not. I tested in Jupyter notebook, stop key is working fine

Comment: I am running this on Spyder

Comment: No, unfortunately, when I press F1 it still works :(

Comment: I tried this on Jupyter, and its working for me. See the attached image in the code above

Comment: I solved the problem by changing while True: to while break_program == True: thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you for confirmation. Please mark my answer as accepted if this is what you were looking for. @mertvnl

Comment: But here is another thing when I press enter it doesn't start again :(

Comment: In that case, return True in both the conditions, check the updated code and see if it works

Comment: I tried the updated code but when I press enter it prints key.enter but does nothing

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, your break statement is not indented properly.

I threw this in repl, and it seemed to work as desired.

```
import keyboard
while True:
   if keyboard.read_key() == 'p':
      print("stopping")
      break
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. P works greatly. It breaks the while loop but if there is no key input the loop doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this?

```
def main():
    openGame()
    while True:
        purchase()
        imageGrab()
        if a.sum() >1200:
            fleaButton()
            time.sleep (0.01)
        grab()
        if b.sum() <=9:
            pressOk()
            time.sleep (0.01)
        if keyboard.read_key() != "p":
            print("Stopping the bot.")
        break


print("Press 'F1' key to stop the bot.")
input("Press enter to start the bot.")

main()
```

just made it opposite to how it was by changing `if keyboard.read_key() == "p":` to `if keyboard.read_key() != "p":` (I haven't tried it myself, but it seems logical).