# Pause the showing of a series of images in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I have the following code

```
the_list=os.listdir(directory)
img_list= [i for i in the_list if i.endswith('.png')]
img_list.sort()

for img_name in img_list:
    img=cv2.imread(img_name)
    cv2.imshow("movie",img)
    #cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.waitKey(10)
```

With this, if I use 0 in waiKey I have to press a key everytime but if I use 10 then I have something "like" a movie where each image is shown after another

My question is, how can I modify the script so that I can press a key to pause or continue the showing of the pics?

Comment: You can use `pynput` for that. See, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60780458/how-to-start-and-break-the-loop-by-pressing-a-key-on-python-3-x

Comment: you should have attempted to solve this yourself and shown your attempt... the solution amounts to keeping "state", changing it upon key press, reacting to different states (different argument to waitKey).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this code but it should work, by pressing p you should be able to pause and unpause:

```
the_list=os.listdir(directory)
img_list= [i for i in the_list if i.endswith('.png')]
img_list.sort()
time_to_wait=10
for img_name in img_list:
    img=cv2.imread(img_name)
    cv2.imshow("movie",img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(time_to_wait)
    if k == ord('p'):
        if time_to_wait == 10:
             time_to_wait=0
        else:
             time_to_wait=10
```